# What is the proof that "reward-to-go" reduces variance of policy gradient?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, proofs, reward-to-go

I am following the OpenAI's spinning up tutorial [Part 3: Intro to Policy Optimization](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html). It is mentioned there that the reward-to-go reduces the variance of the policy gradient. While I understand the intuition behind it, I struggle to find a proof in the literature.

Comment: Does the answer to [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/9614/why-does-the-reward-to-go-trick-in-policy-gradient-methods-work?rq=1) question answer yours as well?

Comment: No, the linked question only proofs that the reward-to-go does not introduce any bias to the gradient estimate.

Comment: This is nontrivial to prove, actually anything involving stochastic function approximation is nontrivial. You can search research papers, you won't find it in any book right now