# What is the return-to-go in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, definitions, reward-to-go

In reinforcement learning, the *return* is defined as some function of the rewards. For example, you can have the *discounted return*, where you multiply the rewards received at later time steps by increasingly smaller numbers, so that the rewards closer to the current time step have a higher weight. You can also have $n$-step returns or $\lambda$-returns.

Recently, I have come across the concept of **return-to-go** in a few research papers, such as [Prioritized Experience Replay](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf) (appendix **A. Prioritization Variants**, p. 12) or [Being Optimistic to Be Conservative: Quickly Learning a CVaR Policy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.01546.pdf) (section **Theoretical Analysis**, p. 3).

What exactly is the *return-to-go*? How is it mathematically defined? In which situations do we need to care about it? The name suggests that this is the return starting from a certain time step $t$, but wouldn't this be the same thing as the *return* (which is defined starting from a certain time step $t$ and often denoted as $G_t$ for that same reason)?

There is also the concept of **reward-to-go**. For example, the reward-to-go is analyzed in the paper [Learning the Variance of the Reward-To-Go](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume17/14-335/14-335.pdf), which states that the *expected reward-to-go* is the value function, which seems to be consistent with [this explanation of the reward-to-go](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html#don-t-let-the-past-distract-you), where the reward-to-go is defined as

$$\hat{R}_{t} \doteq \sum_{t^{\prime}=t}^{T} R\left(s_{t^{\prime}}, a_{t^{\prime}}, s_{t^{\prime}+1}\right)$$

We also had a few questions that involve the reward-to-go: for example, [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21784/2444) or [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/9614/2444). How is the return-to-go related to the reward-to-go? Are they the same thing? For example, in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.02305.pdf), the return-to-go seems to be used as a synonym for reward-to-go (as used in [this article](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html#don-t-let-the-past-distract-you)), i.e. they call $R(t)$ the "return to-go" (e.g. on page 2), which should be the return starting from time step $t$, which should actually be the reward-to-go.

Comment: "return-to-go" is probably not standard terminology, but I think that some people will also have this question (if they come across the same papers), that's why I asked it (i.e. to serve as a future reference).

Comment: so have you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** I the *return-to-go* is just a **synonym** of the *reward-to-go*, which instead is a well known term used to define the basic form of *policy gradient*, e.g. REINFORCE-like.

#### Reward-to-go

As you correctly wrote, the reward-to-go is just a sum of rewards collected in a trajectory $\tau$ from a certain timestep $t$ until termination $T$. If we define $R(\tau)=\sum_{t=1}^T r_t^{\tau}$ as the sum of immediate rewards $r_t$ got in trajectory $\tau$, from that we can define the rewards-to-go just by considering a subset of the trajectory, so discarding the past, i.e starting from a time $t$:
$$R_t(\tau)=\sum_{t'=t}r_{t'}^\tau$$

In particular, the quantity $R_t(\tau)$ figures in the (basic) policy gradient formulation:
$$\nabla_\theta J(\theta)\approx \sum_i\Big(\sum_{t=1}^T \nabla_\theta\log \pi_\theta\big(a_t^{(i)}\mid s_t^{(i)}\big) R_t\big(\tau^{(i)}\big)  \Big)$$

Basically, the rewards-to-go score actions within a trajectory $\tau^{(i)}$: the [spinning-up rl article](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html#don-t-let-the-past-distract-you) you mentioned refers to the fact that the original (although naive) PG formulation uses $R(\tau)$, i.e. sum of rewards, to score the policy's actions but it's useless to consider the immediate rewards $r_k$ gained in the past (so when $k<t$) to score actions happened at time $t$ and onward until the end of the trajectory $T$. In this regard, both $R(\tau)$ and $R_t(\tau)$ are empirical estimates of the value of an action $a_t$ from a given state $s_t$ - think of it as a single-sample estimate of the action-value function, $Q(s_t,a_t)\approx R_t$ - but $R(\tau)$ has a higher variance due the additional sums.

This is reasonable, since in more recent PG formulations we subtract a *baseline function* $b(s)$ to the rewards-to-go to reduce the variance of the gradient estimate: $\nabla_\theta\log\pi_\theta(a_t\mid s_t)(R_t - b(s_t))$. If $b(s)=V(s)$ is chosen to be the value function, then $R_t - b(s_t)$ is an estimate of the advantage function $A(s_t, a_t) = Q(s_t,a_t) - V(s_t)$ since $R_t$ is the action-value gathered in the current trajectory (but not *expected*, as in the Q-function.) Formulations that use $A(s,a)$ yield the gradient with lowest variance: A2C uses this.

> In which situations do we need to care about it?

We talk about rewards-to-go mainly when dealing with the PG estimation, and defining new baseline functions to improve the gradient estimate: otherwise the term return is largely preferred. Note: it is demonstrated that subtracting a baseline does not alter the gradient formulation, and if correctly picked it does not either add bias to the estimate.

> the reward-to-go is analyzed in the paper which states that the *expected* reward-to-go is the value function

The rewards-to-go are more appropriate as action-value estimates rather than state-value estimates (i.e. the return $G_t$) since we start from a state-action pair. This is a technicality that *does not hold* in practice, since the value function is also estimated with empirical returns (i.e. the return of a single trajectory $\tau$), i.e. $G_t(\tau) = r_t^\tau + r_{t+1}^\tau +\cdots + r_T^\tau$ that correspond to the rewards-to-go $R_t(\tau)$: think about learning a value function in deep RL, we just fit the neural-net to empirical returns than MSE + GD does the magic. Now, if we average the collected rewards or returns over all possible trajectories we obtain the *expected return* that is the value function: $V(s_t) = \mathbb{E}_\tau[G_t(\tau)] = \mathbb{E}_\tau[R_t(\tau)] = \mathbb{E}_\tau[r_t^\tau + r_{t+1}^\tau + \cdots + r_{T}^\tau\mid s_t]$.

> How is the return-to-go related to the reward-to-go?

They are same thing. I'd say to avoid "return-to-go" and use return, instead (or at most reward-to-go when talking about PG.)

---

As a side note: none of both terms are mentioned in the famous book "An introduction to reinforcement learning" by Sutton and Barto, so I guess it's something introduced in modern deep RL.