# What is the rigorous proof behind the causality simplification step of off-policy policy gradient

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In [lec5](https://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse/deeprlcourse/static/slides/lec-5.pdf) of Sergey Levine's CS258 on RL, I can understand the derivation of the causality  simplification of on-polciy version below (page 17).

[image]

But what is the detial of the derivation of **the last line** in the PPT below (page 25)?
[image]

It seems that the cumulative reward term and the importance ratio term cannot be decompled and handled one by one.

Comment: casuality =/= causality

Comment: @Alberto Thanks for your kind reminder. Have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may be apparent to many, I'll provide an answer anyway.

In a nutshell, 2 steps:

1. Bring the distribution from $\theta$ to $\theta '$ to cancel the importance ratio term. Use causality to simplify the cumulative reward term to reward-to-go. Details can be found [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/9614/why-does-the-reward-to-go-trick-in-policy-gradient-methods-work?rq=1#:%7E:text=An%20important%20thing,spinningup/extra_pg_proof1.html), which utilized [Expected Grad-Log-Prob Lemma](https://link.zhihu.com/?target=https%3A//spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html%23expected-grad-log-prob-lemma).
2. Bring the distribution back to $\theta$. Use distribution law and the definition of marginal distribution to get the final formula.

proof:

\begin{align}
&\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta}\left[ \left( \prod_{t=1}^{T} \frac{\pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t)}{\pi_{\theta }(a_t|s_t)} \right)\left(\sum_{t=1}^{T}\nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t) \right) \sum_{t=1}^{T}r(s_t,a_t)\right] \\
=&\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta '}\left[\left(\sum_{t=1}^{T}\nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t)\right) \sum_{t=1}^{T}r(s_t,a_t)\right] \\
=& \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta '}\left[\sum_{t=1}^{T}\left(\nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t) \sum_{t'=t}^{T}r(s_{t'},a_{t'})\right)\right] \tag{causility} \\
=& \sum_{t=1}^{T} \sum_{t'=t}^{T} \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta '} \left[\nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t)r(s_{t'},a_{t'}) \right] \tag{distribution law}\\
=& \sum_{t=1}^{T} \sum_{t'=t}^{T} \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta} \left[\prod_{{t''}=1}^{T} \frac{\pi_{\theta '}(a_{t''}|s_{t''})}{\pi_{\theta }(a_{t''}|s_{t''})} \nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t)r(s_{t'},a_{t'}) \right]\\
=& \sum_{t=1}^{T} \sum_{t'=t}^{T} \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta} \left[\prod_{{t''}=1}^{t'} \frac{\pi_{\theta '}(a_{t''}|s_{t''})}{\pi_{\theta }(a_{t''}|s_{t''})} \nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t)r(s_{t'},a_{t'}) \right] \tag{marginal distribution}\\
=& \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta} \left[\sum_{t=1}^{T} \nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t)\sum_{t'=t}^{T} \prod_{{t''}=1}^{t'} \frac{\pi_{\theta '}(a_{t''}|s_{t''})}{\pi_{\theta }(a_{t''}|s_{t''})} r(s_{t'},a_{t'}) \right]\\
=& \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tau\sim \theta} \left[\sum_{t=1}^{T} \nabla_{\theta'}\log \pi_{\theta '}(a_t|s_t)\prod_{{t''}=1}^{t} \frac{\pi_{\theta '}(a_{t''}|s_{t''})}{\pi_{\theta }(a_{t''}|s_{t''})}\sum_{t'=t}^{T}  r(s_{t'},a_{t'})\prod_{{t''}=t}^{t'} \frac{\pi_{\theta '}(a_{t''}|s_{t''})}{\pi_{\theta }(a_{t''}|s_{t''})} \right] \\
\end{align}