# Implementation difference in REINFORCE algorithm, where to sum from

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, reinforce

I have a question regarding the implementation of the REINFORCE algorithm.

In [berkeley course](https://rll.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse/f17docs/lecture_4_policy_gradient.pdf) (see slide 9) the gradient is defined as
[image]

Note that the return **sums from 1**. However in Sutton's book the return **sums from t+1**
[image]

In fact in two popular implementations, [pytorch's official example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py) (See Line 71) and [tianshou's example](https://github.com/thu-ml/tianshou/blob/master/tianshou/policy/modelfree/pg.py#L226) (See Line 226), if I understand correctly, they are computing

```
sum_t (∇log π(a_t | s_t) * R_t)
```

which seems to correspond to Sutton's definition rather than Berkeley's (which will becomes

```
(sum_t ∇log π(a_t | s_t)) * (sum_t r_t)
```

).

I wonder which definition is the de facto standard in the community. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policy gradient objective function of your Berkeley reference is *undiscounted* value function of a start state in finite horizon episodic cases, while the other Sutton's reference at least for the boxed pseudocode is about *discounted* value function of a start state in finite horizon episodic cases as stated in the book:

> From here on in our discussion we will assume no discounting ($\gamma = 1$) for the episodic case, although for completeness we do include the possibility of discounting in the boxed algorithms.

Since the undiscounted total return $G_t$ is defined as $\sum_t^T r_t(s_t,a_t)$, there's no essential notation difference here. Berkeley's equation is an approximation expressed via samples $i$, so it may not be easy to use $G_t$ without further unnecessary confusions such as $G_{t,i}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now. The implementation uses a [reward to go](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html) version, which can be proved to be equivalent to the original loss, see [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/9614/why-does-the-reward-to-go-trick-in-policy-gradient-methods-work).